# Mark a CodeCommit Pull Request as Draft?

Tags: version-control, gitlab-ci, pull-request, cicd, aws-codecommit

I am looking for a way to avoid other dev to merge my pull request before it's ready in CodeCommit, similar to marking a Pull request as a `Draft:` in GitLab so that it can not be merged unless the `Draft:` or `WIP:` keyword is erase from the title (see [this GitLab feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/drafts.html))?

Is this even possible in CodeCommit or do I have to edit my `Approval rule`? If yes, how?

Thank you in advance for your help, have a good day!